# Your app is currently in read only mode because your RBAC assigned access is set to: Reader

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

After the function app deployment in QAS environment it shows
"Your app is currently in read only mode because your RBAC assigned access is set to: Reader "
In dev env shows the below msg but function works as expected.
"Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file. To make any changes update the content in your zip file and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting."

how can i change the readonly to readwrite.

i tried adding config FUNCTION_APP_EDIT_MODE to readwrite its not changing anything.

Answer (score 0):

***You can get rid of this by doing:***

- ***Make the value of **WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE** eqaul to 0, Then click on save. Then restart or republish your function app. You will be able to write also.***

[image]

Comment: If i set the value to 0 getting below error
PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False
PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot
Skipping build. Project type: Run-From-Zip
Skipping post build. Project type: Run-From-Zip
Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
An unknown error has occurred. Check the diagnostic log for details.
##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
##[error]To debug further please check Kudu stack trace URL : ......
##[error]Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.

Comment: Running pip install...
Done in 1141 sec(s).
Command 'starter.sh oryx build /tmp ...' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 60 seconds.